# Express-session установка cookie на разных доменах - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

При заходе на сайт index.php создается сессия на сервере успешно при обновлении страницы она слетает т.к не создаются куки!

При заходе на сайт по site.dev - куки не создаются, а при заходе по 127.0.0.1:8080 - куки создаются
Используется модуль express-session

Как сделать что бы на site.dev создавались куки

Код node.js

```
var app = require('express')(),
  server  = require("http").createServer(app),
  io = require("socket.io")(server),
  session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "dgdsgsdgsdgdsg",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");


app.use(session);

io.use(sharedsession(session));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

    socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
        console.log(socket.handshake.session.userdata);
    });
    socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
        if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
            delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
        }
    });        
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Код site.dev

```
$(function() {
    var socketport = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(target, replacement) {
        return this.split(target).join(replacement);
    };
    var socket = io(socketport, {
        transports: ['websocket']
    }); 
    socket.emit("login", {
            name: 'gasf'
        });
    });
```